# PyMySQL executemany INSERT List from variable

Tags: python-3.x, insert, pymysql, executemany

I am trying to insert some data in a mysql table using pymysql but failing.
The data is held in variables already so I need to pass them to the INSERT statement.

this is what I am currently trying...

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='*.*.*.*', port=***, user='****', 
passwd='***', db='****')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = ("INSERT INTO groupMembers (groupID, members) VALUES (%s, %s)")
    data = (groupID, (x for x in membersList))
    cur.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

the data I am trying to pass looks like the following....

groupID = G9gh472

membersList = [Dave,Bob,Mike,Bill,Colin]

the length of the list is unknown and can vary
the resulting table I want to look like this...

```
| groupID | members |
+---------+---------+
| G9gh472 | Dave    |
| G9gh472 | Bob     |
| G9gh472 | Mike    |
| G9gh472 | Bill    |
| G9gh472 | Colin   |
```

I have tried a few variations of this based on reading others answers, but nothing I have tried so far has worked.
Thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the pymysql docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) the executemany function expects a Sequence of sequences or mappings for the data.

You can do

```
data = list([(groupID, x) for x in membersList]) # Create a list of tuples
```

which should solve the issue. Here is the updated code snippet-

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='*.*.*.*', port=***, user='****', 
passwd='***', db='****')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = ("INSERT INTO groupMembers (groupID, members) VALUES (%s, %s)")
    data = list([(groupID, x) for x in membersList]) # Create a list of tuples
    cur.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: People reading this should remember that %s is a placeholder for a string value, you should use %i for integers values in your own projects.

Answer (score 5):

The data variable you are passing to the `executemany` function is a tuple
but function expects a sequence/mapping.
`cursor.executemany(operation, seq_of_params)` is the function signature. This is why your code is not working.

One way to produce a sequence is as follows.

`product(x,y) returns ((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`

`product([groupId], members)` returns a tuple of tuples (a sequence).

You can refer to the code below -

```
import itertools

    with con.cursor() as cur: # a good practice to follow
        sql = ("INSERT INTO test (id, memb) VALUES (%s, %s)")
        cur.executemany(sql, itertools.product([groupId], members)) # the change needed
    con.commit()
```